# Telebot Как принять фото и перейти в next_step_handler что бы использовать фото далее в сообщении?

Tags: python, telebot

Есть код, в котором спрашивается отправка фото, нужно перейти в next_step_handler с запоминанием в переменную фотографию, что бы вывести ее после.

Answer (score 0):

В общем виде будет выглядеть примерно так

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Send photo")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, get_photo)

def get_photo(message):
    photo = message.photo
```